# In Excel, what formula to use to group numbers and color code them by consecutive numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large list of numbers. I want to group them so that the cell color is the same if the number is a sequential number. If two groups of sequential numbers are beside each other in the list then the color would need to be different.

The list is very large and to color it in manually is taking a very very long time.

If anyone can help me out it would be very appreciated.

Below is an example of a section of Excel that has been manually completed.

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a helper column B, in B1 write 1 if A2=A1+1 or 0 if not and your number list in column A,in B2 write the following formula:
`=IF(A2=A1+1,B1,MOD(B1+1,2))`
then copy down in column B, the result is 1111 or 000
Select column A and use conditional formatting, New Rule,Use Formula to determine which cells to format, write under Format values where this formula is True, the following:
`=B1=0` and Format Yellow
Repeat the same for conditional formatting and use this formula:
`=B1=1` and Format Blue

[image]

[image]